# Allign div with margin-left and margin-right

Tags: css, html

I have a div element with a css like this

```
div.details {
float:right;
margin-right:50px;
margin-left:50px;
```

}

however this only keeps the margin from the right. how can I align the div 50px both from left and right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
div.detais{
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

Or you can be more specific and do something like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/florinpop/pn2jb6u2/).

Comment: Since the OP never mentioned that he wanted the top & bottom margin set to `0`, it might be best to explain _how_ you're using the shorthand notation for `margin`.

Answer (score 0):

It does add margin in both the sides, but since you're floating it to the right, you're able to see only the right margin. If you see another element pushing into this element's left margin, that could be because of some other css. Can you post a jsfiddle in that case?

Florin Pop's answer is good if you want to align the div to the center.